# if function for using dynamic sumif

Tags: excel, vba, countif, sumifs

I would like to use sumif calculation but I would like to avoid sumif function.
In my example below there are 3 expresion in column P, and I would like to find matches in column C and return sum from column L to each of them. It works fine when only one value is entered, but in my case there are 3 values and VBA count them together. How type the code to slice them?

```vb
Sub sumif()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim xlastrow As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
xlastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 16).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To lastrow
   For y = 3 To xlastrow

      If Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(y, 16).Value Then Count = Count + Cells(i, 12).Value
      Cells(y, 16).Offset(0, 1).Value = Count
   Next y
Next i
```

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yJXs.png)]

I expect to return sum's sliced per particular cellvalues from column P

Comment: What benefit do you expect to get from using VBA instead of normal Excel functions?

Comment: I would like for grasp deeply computing operation on behalf and I would like to learn how to separate values in range.

Comment: Maybe the answer in the following link can help you to get started : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75241170/vba-execute-sumif-function-across-sheets-for-all-rows-in-a-column-then-duplicat/75242215#75242215