# VBA execute Sumif function across sheets for all rows in a column, then duplicate the task for different columns and sumranges

Tags: excel, vba, range, sumifs

I have a worksheet (named RsOut) with 235 columns. I need to overwrite the values in only certain columns with data from another sheet(named rsTrans). Both sheets have a unique identifier that I am using to match.

1. I decided to use the Sumif function to populate the rsOut worksheet.  Where I ran into a snag is I cannot figure out how to run the script for all rows in the column that have data.
2. Once we figure this out, I need to repeat this process for roughly 15 other columns.

My over-arching question is even after we get the sumif to work properly, what is the most efficient way to execute the code so that it repeats 15 more times?

The Criteria list and the CriteriaRange will always have the same location. But the Sum Range and the column where the results are inserted will change for each of the 15 columns.

So, Thoughts on the most efficient way to proceed...maybe separate the sumif code as it's own block and call upon it instead of repeating the steps over and over, and/or list out all the sum ranges and all the insert ranges, so the script just loops through them..Would love your insight VBA masters.

Issue:
I think my main issue is that I tried to use a rngList as the criteria.
I also tried to separate the sumif as a separate block of code, to call on. I may have screwed something up there as well.

The error highlights on the Set sumRange row. (Runtime error 1004 - Method 'Range' of Object '_Worksheet' Failed.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!!

```
Sub SumifmovewsTransdatatowsOut()
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim wsTrans As Worksheet, rngList As Range
    
    Dim sumRange As Range
    Dim criteriaRange As Range
    Dim criteria As Long  'Setting as long because the IDs (criteria) are at least 20 characters. Should this be a range??
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsTrans = Worksheets("DEL SOURCE_Translator")  'Worksheet that contains analysis and results that need to be inserted into wsOut
        
    Set wsOut = Worksheets("FID GDMR - Output_2") 'Worksheet where you are pasting results from wsTrans
    Set rngList = wsOut.Range("B2:B" & wsOut.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)  'this range of IDs will be different every run, thus adding in the count to find last row...or do I not need the rnglist at all? Just run the sumif for all criteria B2:b
    
    Set sumRange = wsTrans.Range("ag21:ag")  'Values in wsTrans that need to be added to wsOut
    Set criteriaRange = wsTrans.Range("AA21:AA")  'Range of IDs found on wsTrans
    criteria = rngList
                   
    Sumif
  
End Sub

'Standard Sumif formula
Sub Sumif()
     wsOut.Range("AT2:AT") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(sumRange, criteriaRange, criteria)
End Sub
'OR should the Sumif formula be:   rng.Formula = "=SUMIF(criteriaRange,rngList,sumRange)"
```

SUBSEQUENT TESTING after receiving recommendations:
I tested using the second recommendation only because a future user could easily change out the array values if the columns shifted on the wsout template.  Below is the code that I used and the resulting error.

Result issues:

1. the result in each changed cell is #NAME?
2. a pop up box shows up for each request. It is looking for the translater. See screenshot below. If I x out of each pop up box, the script completes and each cell has the #NAME?
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elhdN.png)

Thoughts on what went wrong?

Code:

```
    Sub test2()
Dim wsTrans As Worksheet: Dim wsOut As Worksheet
Dim rgCrit As String: Dim rgSum As String
Dim rgR As Range: Dim i As Integer: Dim arr

arr = Array("AG:AT", "AJ:BB", "AM:BJ", "AT:BR", "AZ:CA", "BP:DE", "BW:DO") 'change as needed
Set wsTrans = Sheets("DEL SOURCE_Translator")         'change as needed
Set wsOut = Sheets("FID GDMR - Output_2")           'change as needed
rgCrit = wsTrans.Name & "!" & wsTrans.Columns(27).Address  'Column 27 is AA in wsTrans which contains the criteria range
Set rgR = wsOut.Range("B2", wsOut.Range("B2").End(xlDown)) 'change as needed
startCell = "$" & Replace(rgR(1, 1).Address, "$", "")

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    rgSum = wsTrans.Name & "!" & Split(arr(i), ":")(0) & ":" & Split(arr(i), ":")(0)
        With rgR.Offset(0, Range(Split(arr(i), ":")(1) & 1).Column - rgR.Column)
            .Value = "=SUMIF(" & rgCrit & "," & startCell & "," & rgSum & ")"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
Next

End Sub


'Sum Ranges in wsTrans:     AG, AJ, AM, AT, AZ, BP, BW
'Result Columns in wsOut:   AT, BB, BJ, BR, CA, DE, DO
```

Additional Review:
Also, to test, instead of x'ing out of the pop up, I selected my file in the pop up. when I did, a second pop up below showed up.  Interestingly, the sheet name is missing the DEL on the front. When I select the correct sheet, I still get the #Name? error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KC87.png)

Comment: Thank you both!!  I will dig in. Alot to digest here.   

The sum columns and the result columns both have the same column headers. So we could use a match formula ,..Column header names will not change.  

Otherwise, columns are at random. wsTrans sumranges are: AG, AJ, AM, AT, AZ, BP, BW.
wsOut are AT, BB, BJ, BR, CA, DE, DO  
Thank you both so much for your help!

Comment: Have you step run the code and check each variable ? example : if variable is a string/integer, then check the value in the Locals window.... if the variable is a range, then put a helper code to select that variable range (don't forget to activate the regarding sheet first) and see if it select the correct range. You wrote : _a pop up box shows up for each request_. In what code line when you step run it ? Is it when the yellow want to pass this line? `With rgR.Offset(0, Range(Split(arr(i), ":")(1) & 1).Column - rgR.Column)`

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I stepped in and the pop up box occurs when the following row is highlighted and I then hit F8. 
.Value = "=SUMIF(" & rgCrit & "," & startCell & "," & rgSum & ")"

Comment: Also, to test, instead of x'ing out of the pop up, I selected my file in the pop up. when I did, a second pop up below showed up.  Interestingly, the sheet name is missing the DEL on the front. When I select the correct sheet, I still get the #Name? error.  I can't paste here in the comment field , so adding up above.

Comment: Could the error be related to the addition of .Name to the section below? I am not sure what this section is doing. Defining the criteria to be a range in the wsTrans, with data in Column 27, (which is AA). What does  "!" do? I can't find online what an exclamation mark does.  
rgCrit = wsTrans.Name & "!" & wsTrans.Columns(27).Address

Comment: Sorry, I just realize that your sheet name has space. So maybe try this : `rgCrit = "'" & wsTrans.Name & "'" & "!" & wsTrans.Columns(27).Address`. Also `rgSum = "'" & wsTrans.Name & "'" & "!" & Split(arr(i), ":")(0) & ":" & Split(arr(i), ":")(0)`

Comment: I myself is not an expert, so I am very sorry as I don't know what is the exclamation mark do. The thing I know is that if I manually make a formula in one sheet like this : in sheet1 klik cell A1, type : = .... then activate sheet2 klik cell A2, hit enter. Then the formula result in sheet1 A1 is like this : `=sheet2!A2`. Then if the sheet name has a space "sheet bla", the formula result is like this : `='sheet bla'!A2`

Comment: That worked!!.  I will do more testing, but it works! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so your question is a little too broad for this website. The general rule is each question should address one specific issue.
That being said, I think I can help you with a few easy to solve points.

**1) Making Sumif Work:**
Using `Sumif()` function inside a Sub is the same as using it in an Excel formula. First you need two **full** ranges, next you need a value to lookup.
**Full** ranges: `wsTrans.Range("ag21:ag")` is not going to work because it doesn't have an end row. Instead, it needs to be `wsTrans.Range("AG21:AG100")`. Now since you don't seem to know your last row, I would suggest you find that first and then integrate it into all your ranges. I'm using the variable `lRow` below.

```
Option Explicit
Sub TestSum2()
    
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim wsTrans As Worksheet
    Dim wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim criteriaRange As Range
    Dim sumRange As Range
    Dim rngList As Range
    Dim aCriteria    'Array
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsTrans = WB.Worksheets("DEL SOURCE_Translator")
    
    Set wsOut = WB.Worksheets("FID GDMR - Output_2")
    
    lRow = wsOut.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngList = wsOut.Range("B2:B" & lRow)
    aCriteria = rngList  'Transfer Range to array
    
    lRow = wsTrans.Range("AA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set sumRange = wsTrans.Range("AG21:AG" & lRow)
    Set criteriaRange = wsTrans.Range("AA21:AA" & lRow)
    
    Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(criteriaRange, aCriteria(1, 1), sumRange)
    
End Sub
```

The above sub returns:

[image]

Which is correct considering the following sheets:
[image]
[image]

---

**2) Making it loop through the criteria list**
You've already made a great start on looping through this criteria list by importing `rngList` into an array. Next we just need to loop that array like so:

```
Option Explicit
Sub TestSum2()
    
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim wsTrans As Worksheet
    Dim wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim criteriaRange As Range
    Dim sumRange As Range
    Dim rngList As Range
    Dim aCriteria    'Array
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim I As Long
    
    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsTrans = WB.Worksheets("DEL SOURCE_Translator")
    
    Set wsOut = WB.Worksheets("FID GDMR - Output_2")
    
    lRow = wsOut.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngList = wsOut.Range("B2:B" & lRow)
    aCriteria = rngList  'Transfer Range to array
    
    lRow = wsTrans.Range("AA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set sumRange = wsTrans.Range("AG21:AG" & lRow)
    Set criteriaRange = wsTrans.Range("AA21:AA" & lRow)
    
    For I = 1 To UBound(aCriteria, 1)
        Debug.Print "Sum of " & aCriteria(I, 1) & "=" & _
            Application.WorksheetFunction. _
            SumIf(criteriaRange, aCriteria(I, 1), sumRange)
    Next I
    
End Sub
```

This results in an output of:

[image]

Then to finish it off, you'll need to check which column to put it in, maybe with a `.Find` or maybe with a `Match()` of the column headers, but I don't know what your data looks like. But, if you just want to output that range to your output sheet here's how to do that:

```
Sub TestSum2()
    
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim wsTrans As Worksheet
    Dim wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim criteriaRange As Range
    Dim sumRange As Range
    Dim rngList As Range
    Dim aCriteria    'Array
    Dim OutputSums
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim I As Long
    
    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsTrans = WB.Worksheets("DEL SOURCE_Translator")
    
    Set wsOut = WB.Worksheets("FID GDMR - Output_2")
    
    lRow = wsOut.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngList = wsOut.Range("B2:B" & lRow)
    aCriteria = rngList  'Transfer Range to array
    
    lRow = wsTrans.Range("AA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set sumRange = wsTrans.Range("AG21:AG" & lRow)
    Set criteriaRange = wsTrans.Range("AA21:AA" & lRow)
    
    ReDim OutputSums(1 To UBound(aCriteria, 1), 1 To 1)
    For I = 1 To UBound(aCriteria, 1)
        OutputSums(I, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
            SumIf(criteriaRange, aCriteria(I, 1), sumRange)
    Next I
    wsOut.Range("C2").Resize(UBound(OutputSums, 1), 1) = OutputSums
    
End Sub
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, besides Mr. Cameron's answers, another way maybe you can have the VBA using formula.

Before running the sub is something like this :
[image]

After running the sub (expected result) is something like this:
[image]

Please ignore the fill color, the sorting and the value, as they are used is just to be easier to calculate manually for the expected result.

> The Criteria list and the CriteriaRange will always have the same
> location. But the Sum Range and the column where the results are
> inserted will change for each of the 15 columns.

Since you don't mention where are the columns for the Sum Range will be, this code assume that it will be in a consecutive column to the right of column ID, as seen in the image of sheet1 ---> rgSUM1, rgSUM2, rgSUM3.

And because you also don't mention in what column in sheet2 the result is, this code assume that it will be in a consecutive column to the right of column ID, as seen in the image of sheet2 ---> SUM1, SUM2, SUM3.

If your Sum Range columns are random and/or your Sum Result columns are random, then you can't use this code. For example : your rgSum1 is in column D sheet1 - rgSum1Result sheet2 column Z, rgSum2 is in column AZ sheet1 - rgSum2Result sheet2 column F, rgSum3 is in column Q sheet1 - rgSum3Result sheet2 column DK, and so on until 15 columns. I think it will need an array of column letter for both rgSum and rgSumResult if they are random.

```
Sub test()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet: Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim rgCrit As String: Dim rgSum As String
Dim rgR As Range: Dim col As Integer

col = 3 'change as needed
Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1") 'change as needed
Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2") 'change as needed
rgCrit = sh1.Name & "!" & sh1.Columns(1).Address 'change as needed
rgSum = sh1.Name & "!" & Replace(sh1.Columns(2).Address, "$", "") 'change as needed
Set rgR = sh2.Range("A2", sh2.Range("A2").End(xlDown)) 'change as needed
startCell = "$" & Replace(rgR(1, 1).Address, "$", "")

With rgR.Resize(rgR.Rows.Count, col).Offset(0, 1)
    .Value = "=SUMIF(" & rgCrit & "," & startCell  & "," & rgSum & ")"
    .Value = .Value
End With

End Sub
```

Basically the code just fill the range of the expected result with SUMIF formula.

col = how many columns are there as the sum range
sh1 (wsTrans in your case) is the sheet where the ID and the multiple sum range are. 
sh2 (wsOut in your case) is the sheet where the ID to sum and the multiple sum result are.

rgCrit is the sh1 name with the column of the range of criteria (column A, (ID) in this case)
rgSum is the sh1 name with the first column of Sum Range (column B in this case)

rgR is the range of the unique ID in sheet2 (column A in this case, must have no blank cell in between, because it use xldown) and finally, startCell is the first cell address of rgR

Below if the SumRange and ResultRange are random column.

```
Sub test2()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet: Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim rgCrit As String: Dim rgSum As String
Dim rgR As Range: Dim i As Integer: Dim arr

arr = Array("B:G", "F:E", "D:B") 'change as needed
Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet13") 'change as needed
Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet14") 'change as needed
rgCrit = sh1.Name & "!" & sh1.Columns(1).Address 'change as needed
Set rgR = sh2.Range("A2", sh2.Range("A2").End(xlDown)) 'change as needed
startCell = "$" & Replace(rgR(1, 1).Address, "$", "")

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    rgSum = sh1.Name & "!" & Split(arr(i), ":")(0) & ":" & Split(arr(i), ":")(0)
        With rgR.Offset(0, Range(Split(arr(i), ":")(1) & 1).Column - rgR.Column)
            .Value = "=SUMIF(" & rgCrit & "," & startCell & "," & rgSum & ")"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
Next

End Sub
```

The arr value is in pair : sum range column - sum result column.

Example arr in code :
First loop : sum range column is B (sheet1) where the result will be in column G (sheet2).
Second loop: sum range column is F (sheet1) where the result will be in column E (sheet2).
Third loop: sum range column is D (sheet1) where the result will be in column B (sheet2).

Comment: The other wrinkle, when looking at the Array in Karma's code: 
arr = Array("B:G", "F:E", "D:B") 'change as needed

The array is from B:G.  My wsTrans column headers are in row 20, and the data starts on row 21.  So in the above example would that be:
arr = Array("(B21:B):G",.....OR will that get too complex. To keep it simple, I could insert a row at the top and copy all the column headers into Row 1.  Today, Rows 1 - 19 have other analysis data but will never have an ID, so this could work.

Comment: @user912205 you can have a range address like `"B:B"` or like `"B21:B56"` but **not** like `"B21:B"` .

Comment: As long as from row 1 to row 20 there is no criteria value and value to sum, I think it should be alright to just the whole column. Using my data in sheet1, but the table starts from A21. So, in A21:D21 is the header name. As long as in between row 1 to row 20 there is no something like : A3 value aaa, B3 value 123 ... then I think it should be ok to use rgCrit with the whole column and rgSum with the whole column. The same with this situation (based on my image data) : table datarange ---> A21:D38. But then there is "bbb" in A1000 and there is "123" in C1000 ---> will give not correct result.